# Convert a html table markup to MS Word table programmatically

Tags: .net, ms-word, html-table

I've got a markup for a html table stored in a variable. It will basically contain the start and end tag for a table:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      ...
   </tr>
   .
   .
</table>
```

I need this to appear as a table in my word document. Of course, my word document is programmatically "open"; there are other sections to fill in the word document. Its only at a certain section in the document I want to insert this table.

Would appreciate if people gave me some directions on how to achieve this? I am looking for some .net code to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an altChunk, provided the document is to be opened in Word (since Word will do the work to convert the HTML). Word is not required at the time the document is created; only for opening it.

In terms of Microsoft's OpenXML SDK classes: you want AlternativeFormatImportPart of type AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html or Xhtml or if you have images in your table, Mht.

See http://sunnyhasan.blogspot.com/2010/04/html-to-word-document-converter-using.html or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/d8595e50-76f6-42ab-a7d7-7bfc92a3655e/ for examples

Comment: The OpenXML SDK? We have to install this separately? What version of MS Office do I need to work this?

Comment: Yes, download it and install it.  It is a library for .NET; MS Office is not required, although of course you will want to check your resulting documents open in Word.  Certainly 2007 is enough to process an AFIP; maybe 2003 with compatibility pack also.