# Copy Html tables using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I need to copy an HTML table and write it into a word doc. A sample of my HTML is

```
<table id="intimation" runat="server">
<tr>
<td>
test page
</td>
<td>
new test
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
test page
</td>
<td>
new test
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to copy this table into a string .. then i can esily insert it into the word doc

Comment: Duplicate of [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108901/convert-a-html-table-markup-to-ms-word-table-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) seems to be what you need. Take a look at its documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response .. Is there any possibility to work without third party tools

Comment: There certainly is -- write the code to fetch results you need yourself. Your particular example could perhaps be solved concatenating everything between `<td>` and `</td>` to your string. There are probably many pitfalls in that approach, and that's why it is a good idea to use a library that already solves your problems.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `StreamWriter` to write and if you want to store `HTML` in `string` type variable, you can achieve it as following:

```
string TestHTML = "<table id=\"intimation\" runat=\"server\">";
```

if you put the backslash (`\`) infront of double quotes (`"`), it will allow you to store the double quotes in string variable. But backslash (`\`) will not appear in written file.

```
string TestHTML = "<table id=\"intimation\" runat=\"server\">" +
"<tr><td>test page</td><td>new test</td></tr>" +
"<tr><td>test page</td>" +
"<td>new test</td></tr>" +
"</table>";
```

Comment: but personally I would recommend you to use the power of XSLT, because its very easy for maintenance.

Comment: I was under the impression that the OP required reading a html file, not writing it. Perhaps I was mistaken. The XSLT suggestion could be used for reading as well, if the document is well formed (it seems to be).

Comment: @ipavlic to be honest, I never used `XSLT` for reading but its very useful for generating `HTML`. I think in this case, he is trying to store HTML in a string type variable so he car write it on file. If we use a `XSLT` to create `HTML` from `XML`, it will provide us more flexibility.